# Is "Bridge that gap" correct?

Tags: word-usage

I know "bridge the gap" is the correct phrase but is it allowed to use the variation? For instance- "Bridge that gap between sales and marketing."

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Could you cite your research? And perhaps why you think your phrase might or not be correct?

Comment: Years ago there was a TV ad in the UK for a chocolate product, the idea being that one can get hungry between meals - the slogan was "Bridge that gap with Cadbury's Snack".

Comment: With the Cadbury slogan, the implied referent was vaguely recoverable (gap between mealtimes and/or empty stomach). Using 'that' rather than 'the' was pragmatically indicating a familiarity the viewer had with the desire for a nibble (and also sounded a lot better). Using it in the way you suggest is certainly not ungrammatical, but will in older people invoke nostalgia for the consumer age of the 60's. It may still work; it certainly worked for {Cadbury, formerly Cadbury's and Cadbury Schweppes} (but look how good their product is). But it could be felt to be over-familiarity.

Comment: I have just seen a picture of a Cadbury poster with a trilby-wearing man-in-a-hurry headed "Bridge that gap (etc)". The year was 1956, which surprised me slightly.

Answer (score 0):

**bridge the gap** is an AmE idiom  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bridge+the+gap)

> Fig. to do or create something that will serve temporarily.

As in:

*X can bridge the gap between sales and marketing.*

X =  employee, a different department etc...